# How to use Select2 in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, jquery-select2, nuxtjs3

The question is simple, how to use select2 in nuxt3?

select2 from https://select2.org/

nuxt3 from [v3.nuxtjs.org](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I have spent few days to do this, but failed. Finally I made my own npm package. Think might be useful for others, so here is how to do it:

**1 npm install**

```
npm install nuxt3-select2 --save
```

**2 create a plugin**
// plugins/select2.client.ts

```
import Select2 from 'nuxt3-select2';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("Select2", Select2, {});
});
```

**3 use it in template**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Select2 v-model="myValue" :options="myOptions" :settings="{ settingOption: value, settingOption: value }" @change="myChangeEvent($event)" @select="mySelectEvent($event)" />
    <h4>Value: {{ myValue }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
  const myChangeEvent = (event) => {
    console.log("myChangeEvent: ", event);
  }
  const mySelectEvent = (e) => {
    console.log("mySelectEvent: ", event);
  }
  const myOptions = [
    {id: 1, text: 'apple'},
    {id: 2, text: 'berry'},
    {id: 3, text: 'cherry'},
  ]
  const myValue = ref();
</script>
```

you can read more documentation here: [nuxt3-select2](https://github.com/jackysupit/nuxt3-select2/tree/for-nuxt3)